# cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'System.Action'

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I have created retry mechanism in our micro service application.But facing conversion issue in GetAsync method call.

List policy has been during initialization of class

```
static TimeoutPolicy _timeoutPolicy = Policy.Timeout(1);
static RetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> _httpRetryPolicy = Policy
        .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
        .Retry(3);

response =  _httpFallbackPolicy.Execute(() =>
            _httpRetryPolicy.Execute(() =>
            _timeoutPolicy.Execute(client.GetAsync(uri).Result)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code have several problems. Let's go through all of them one by one.

#### Combining policies

There are three ways how you can combine multiple policies

1.

```
_httpFallbackPolicy.Execute(() => _httpRetryPolicy.Execute(() => _timeoutPolicy.Execute(() => ...)));
```

2. 

```
_httpFallbackPolicy.Wrap(_httpRetryPolicy).Wrap(_timeoutPolicy).Execute(() => ...);
```

3. 

```
Policy.Wrap(_httpFallbackPolicy, _httpRetryPolicy,_timeoutPolicy).Execute(() => ...);
```

- The very first one is tedious and error-prone
- The second and third are more concise and less error-prone
- I personally suggest the third one

The first one is error-prone because the policies can be defined in a way that they are not compatible. In the 2nd and 3rd cases the compiler enforces that all combined policies are compatible. In your case all policies should be defined as `ISyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`.

#### Action vs HttpResponseMessage

Whenever you issue this command `client.GetAsync(uri).Result)` you are basically saying send a GET request, block the thread, and wait for its result.

The policies are designed to decorate actions, so you need to pass an operation to the `Execute`, not a response object:

```
.Execute(() => client.GetAsync(uri).Result)
```

If you really want to stick to the synchronous API call (which you **should not**) then please prefer `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` over `.Result` to receive the exception unfolded. (With `.Result` you would receive an `AggregateException`):

```
.Execute(() => client.GetAsync(uri).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
```

#### Prefer async over sync

Each policy can be defined in an asynchronous way. They are betted suited to decorate async methods:

```
IAsyncPolicy _timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync(1);
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> _httpRetryPolicy = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
    .RetryAsync(3);
```

### Put things all together

So, if you apply all the above suggestions you would get a code like this:

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> _httpFallbackPolicy = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>.Handle<...>().FallbackAsync(...);
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> _timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(1);
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> _httpRetryPolicy = Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    .Or<TimeoutRejectedException>()
    .RetryAsync(3);

var resilientStrategy = Policy.WrapAsync(_httpFallbackPolicy, _httpRetryPolicy, _timeoutPolicy);

var result = await resilientStrategy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await client.GetAsync(uri));
```